# want to display a browser add exception for my https url on iframe in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

I am displaying a 'https' url on a iframe tag and I have created self signed certificate for that url. But in iframe, when I display the url it does not pop the add exception on the iframe itself but I have to manually open that url into a different tab and then accept the exception.

I want to display that url exception on the iframe so that I can add the exception then and there instead of opening it different tab.

Please help me with this if it is possible with iframe or any other way. I am fairly new to javascript.

Thank you.

Comment: It is up to the browser, whether it wants to ask the user to add such an exception. I don't think there is anything you can do about this.

Comment: The browser (chrome and firefox alteast) are showing the exception. but when I open the same url through iframe there is not display at all.
I want to show the same exception as browser on the iframe.

Comment: Basically I want to display the whole browser page without the url on top

Comment: _"but when I open the same url through iframe there is not display at all"_ - yes, and I am saying that is probably a _deliberate_ decision (similar to how browsers do not prompt for HTTP auth credentials any more, when the requested resource is from a different domain.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Is there another way to do this? like any other html tag which displays web browser as it.

Comment: `object` maybe, but I don't think that will solve your underlying problem either. _"Basically I want to display the whole browser page without the url on top"_ - that's the _whole_ purpose? Like, "hiding" the URL because it is "ugly", or you think it was insecure? Those would not be good reasons to use iframe, especially with all the usability drawbacks.